# Use Redis than Mysql to store location history of app user

Tags: mysql, redis

Is a good idea use Redis as a persistent database(AOF strategy) to store information about geodata?

For example, instead you store all positions of a user inside mysql, I want to use redis. But I am afraid of persistence problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis persistence is not the same as durability in an ACID database. Trying to make Redis maximally durable (insofar as it can) will limit its performance and lead to large log files. You can relax persistence by various configuration options, but this naturally leads to a compromise on durability.

You should read more about it:

- https://redis.io/topics/persistence
- http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/redis-persistence-demystified.html

Personally, I would not use Redis as a primary data store for any data that could not be reproduced easily. That would not be using Redis for its strength, in any case.

Comment: Would you use postgree as primary data store than mysql? Or mongodb it's a better choice?

Comment: MySQL and PostgreSQL are both good choices. The differences between those two are small enough that you should just use the one you feel more comfortable with. MongoDB is not a good choice if you need durability.

Comment: Sorry to be redundant, just more one question. Suppose the common user case is to load a user day route. Would be a good idea to store all this information inside files with a pattern name like 2017-31-01_(user id).csv, and load this information to redis when necessary?

https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/2016/11/16/blazingly-fast-geospatial-queries-with-redis/

Comment: I can't answer that without knowing your application and its data-handling requirements. But it sounds like it would satisfy what I mentioned in my answer about data being easily recoverable in case Redis loses it. Make sure your files are backed up!

Comment: I can't answer that without knowing your application and its data-handling requirements. But it sounds like it would satisfy what I mentioned in my answer about data being easily recoverable in case Redis loses it. Make sure your files are backed up!